# Linux (C) Signal Hanlding

Tags: c, linux, signals

My simple code will catch all the signals and show what signal you  triggered at what exact time, but my problem is when the signal is caught the code will end and I couldn't trigger any other signal other SIGINT how can I trigger like (SIGSEGV , SIGABRT)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
//bos501_hw_signals_handling_Linux
void sig_handler(int signo)
{ time_t current_time;
    char* c_time_string;
    //Catch the current time. /
    current_time = time(NULL);
    // Convert to local time  /
    c_time_string = ctime(&current_time);
//putting a condition for signals when they are caught to print the signal.
    if (signo == SIGINT)
printf("received SIGUSR1\n"" ::Current time is %s", c_time_string);
    else if (signo == SIGSEGV)
printf("received SIGSEGV\n"" ::Current time is %s", c_time_string);
    else if (signo == SIGABRT)
printf("received SIGABRT\n"" ::Current time is %s", c_time_string);
    else if (signo == SIGKILL)
printf("received SIGKILL\n"" ::Current time is %s", c_time_string);
    else if (signo == SIGSTOP)
printf("received SIGSTOP\n"" ::Current time is %s", c_time_string);
}

int main(void)
{    //putting a conditon to show the signal that isnt caught like (SIGKILL,SIGSTOP)
    if (signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGUSR1\n");
    if (signal(SIGSEGV, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGSEGV\n");
    if (signal(SIGABRT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGABRT\n");
    if (signal(SIGKILL, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGKILL\n");
    if (signal(SIGSTOP, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGSTOP\n");
    // long wait to process the signal 
    while (1)
        sleep(1);
    return 0;
    //end of code
}
```

Comment: Use of `stdio` functions in signal handlers is discouraged. Take a look at [`signal-safety(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) for a list of async-signal-safe functions.

Answer (score 1):

1. SIGKILL and SIGSTOP signals cannot be caught, blocked or ignored. For these, the default action always happens.
2. The signal system call is deprecated. Use the sigaction system call for setting the signal action.
3. printf should not be used in signal handler. Use the write system call on file descripter 2 instead.

Comment: how do i use the sigaction system call, and yes i want to ignore the other two signals that i have mentioned not (SIGSTOP,SIGKILL) how can i do that please

Comment: You can't ignore SIGSTOP and SIGKILL. If either of these signals come, the default action associated with them will happen. For an example of how to use sigaction system call, please refer to https://www.softprayog.in/programming/signals-in-linux